# Google assistant python demo error "Security handshake failed"

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to do a google assistant demo (using python library) to stakeholder, but I would see this error from time to time:

> E1203 23:35:57.700629400    2009 handshake.c:128]            Security
>   handshake failed:
>   {"created":"@1512372957.700516840","description":"Handshake read
>   failed","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1512372957.700504360","description":"FD
>   shutdown","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":1045}]}

I do see the other topic discussing about this issue, network maybe the root cause.

But is there any workaround for this issue since changing the network is not that easy and can't be under control.

Sometimes re-creating the credential would seem to be able to fix this error, but sometimes not.

I mean, I can live with this error till the next release, but is there any way that I can make it work just for current minute once it occurs?

And another thing is, once the error shows up, the python demo stop running.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Actually I don't really write any code here,  I follow the google assistant sdk guide: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/python/config-dev-project-and-account to run the python demo